TLC59116 LED Driver circuit to drive two pin bicolor LEDs
I'm planning to use one or more TLC59116 LED drivers to control 14 two pin bicolor (green and red) LEDs and I'm struggling to find a way to connect these to the LED driver.

The LED maximum Vf is ~2.5 V
The LED forward current is 20 mA.
The power supply is 3.3 V

Is there a simple way to do the trick with this type of LEDs using this specific driver?
If not, is there a LED driver type more suitable to this type of LEDs?

If the LEDs are common "anode", yes, they could be used. What kind of LEDs are you using?

Hi @Antonio51, thanks for your message. The LEDs I'll be using are the ones integrated in this switch: https://configured-product-images.s3.amazonaws.com/Datasheets/TL1220.pdf

Ok. Note that the LEDs used need an "inversion" of the polarity. So, this circuit can't do it in its "primitive" task. The solution presented by @Mattman944 should be a "good" one.

You don't need a fancy LED driver to drive low-power LEDs. Modern LEDs are plenty bright at 5 mA or lower.
I would use a 74AC244 and drive at 5 mA. If you really need to drive at higher currents, you will need a more powerful driver.
Drive one signal high and the other low for 1 LED on. Drive both signals the same for both LEDs off.
Edit: if you don't have enough GPIOs, then use an I/O Expander such as a TI TCAL9539. You can find them with enough output current to drive LEDs.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Thanks for your answer. That's right, and that is what I planned but unfortunately I have not enough IOs in my MCU. The LEDs should remain ON or OFF randfomly and therefore I decided to go LEd driver wise. Nonetheless, do you think using a 16 channel MUX could do the trick? I'm afraid this solution could present some flickering or changes in the LEDs when operating them...

@LazyTurtle - I added an option with an I/O expander.
